# first child in jquery

Tags: jquery

HTML:

```
        <div class="wrapper" style="display:none">
          <div class="panel"></div>
        </div>
```

JS CALL

```
var element = $(".wrapper");
element.toggle().children(":first").custom();
$(".wrapper .panel").custom();
```

CUSTOM JQUERY METHOD

```
  $.fn.custom = function() {  
        return this.each(function() {
           console.log(" this = ", this);
               // do something to each dom element.
        });
    };
```

Whats odd here is when I do a console.log in IE its showing the first call to the panel element as a

**[object HTMLGenericElement]**

but the second call shows it as a **[objectHTMLDIVElement]**

Why is this and how to have the first call be a [objectHTMLDIVElement]

Answer (score 1):

You should use `$(this)` instead of `this` inside the `each` function.

```
return this.each(function() {
    console.log(" this = ", $(this));
    // do something to each dom element.
})
```

Besides, I checked [this](http://jsfiddle.net/PBygE/) with chrome, safari, firefox and everywhere I am receiving the `<div>` element

Comment: Still comes back with the same results

Comment: @SKS, Why dont you see the [basic plugin authoring](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) page

Comment: @Starx Which contradicts your answer. Anyway, the OP says the results are the same.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZEXvW/), they are both logged as **[object HTMLDivElement]**.

Tested in IE9 (Version 9.0.8112.16421 64-bit).